# Need for the -n option in netcat

Tags: dns, services, netcat

According to `man nc`

> -n      Do not do any DNS or service lookups on any specified addresses, hostnames or ports.

What I do not understand is why it needs to do any service lookup (also I do not know what services it is talking about for hostnames, addresses or ports except DNS) and if it is done, why is there a need to stop it for some specific netcat commands?

Answer (score 1):

- DNS resolution works both ways, i.e. it allows to convert a hostname to an IP address and vice versa. When you just want to use `nc` without doing any DNS resolution (which might be not working properly for you), you'll run it with `-n` to avoid any issues.
- Service lookups is what is resolved via e.g. `/etc/services`, e.g. you may run `nc` this way:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 http
```

then `http` will be resolved to 80 via this file. You may also want to avoid using this feature.

There are many more ways to resolve (Name Service Switch), see

```
info libc 'NSS Basics'
```